# Убрать отображение полос прокрутки

Tags: html, css

У меня есть небольшой блок и полосы прокрутки к нему. Надо чтобы полосы прокрутки работали (колесом крутить если), а сами полосы не были видны. `hidden` убирает их, но работоспособность также проходит.

Comment: Возможно, одно из [этих свойств][1] подойдет.


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/35329/

Comment: [Вот тут всё подробно расписано](http://htmlbook.ru/css/overflow)

Answer (score 2):

Что бы блок прокручивался - а полос не было - это нужно внедрять жску. Есть много плагинов, которые скрывают полосы прокрутки, но сам скол работает. А средствами ксс - не видел такого еще.

Вот один из них **[slimscroll](https://github.com/rochal/jQuery-slimScroll)**

Answer (score 1):

в css

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
visibility: hidden;
width: 0px;
}
```

Comment: а с остальными браузерами что прикажите делать?

Comment: К сожалению,такой способ доступен лишь на нескольких браузерах,но,будем надеется,что его внедрят и в другие браузеры

Comment: кроме того есть решение для mc explorer: html{-ms-overflow-style: none;} так-же было overflow: -moz-scrollbars-none;  для мозиллы,но сей-час оно работает не так как надо)